# What are the minimal configuration for to switch wcf to remorting?

Tags: wcf

We have WCF with wsHttpBinding now want to convert it on remoting how to do ?

Comment: Why do you want to convert from WCF to Remoting? It would help me figure out what to tell you.

Comment: Now client want to move application in intranet.

Comment: Absolutely unclear what the question is .... please rephrase and give more detail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF and remoting (.NET remoting) are two different technologies. Switching mean rewritting integration part of all your server components and clients.

.NET remoting is "replaced" by WCF with netTcpBinding so you should start with changing your binding to netTcp and see if your clinet will be satisfied.

Comment: thanks Ladislav, I am doing that but tell me we need to change binding in both side in server and in the proxy class (client side) created by svcutil.exc

Comment: Yes you have to change binding on both sides or regenerate proxy.